# How do I make my input pick up words rather than letters? (Python)

Tags: python, string, list, random

I'm trying to make a random name picker for me and my friends.

The problem I have is that if I enter a bunch of names the output gives me 5 separate letters picked from our names rather than our full names.

[Example of the output I receive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IERuk.png)

Here's my code so far.

```
import random

print("Random Name Picker")

input_string = str(input("Input names: "))
if input_string == "exit":
    exit()
nameList = input_string.split()
print("Our contestants for this round are:", nameList)

sampled_list = random.choices(input_string, k=5)
print("Our winners are:", sampled_list)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
Let me know if you need any more information.

Thank you!

**EDIT:** I've fixed it, and I also no longer get repeat names in my code.
Here is the fixed program for anyone in the future

```
import random

print("Random Name Picker")

input_string = input("Input names: ")
if input_string == "exit":
    exit()
nameList = input_string.split() # by default it will split by space 
print("Our contestants for this round are:", nameList)

sampled_list = random.sample(nameList, k=5)
print("Our winners are:", sampled_list)
```

The main changes are:

- including () after `input_string.split()` to appropriately split my input. Also by default, It will split by space so no need to indicate `(" ")` in `split()`.
- putting `name_list` after **`random.sample()`** (instead of `random.choices()`) rather than input_string

Thank you very much to the people who helped me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pick random choices from the `nameList` instead of the `input_string`.

The `input_string` is a string that hasn't been split yet, so `random.choices` returns characters. The `nameList` is a list of strings, so `random.choices` will return entries of the list.

Comment: Awesome! It's working as intended now. Thank you for explaining it, the helps me wrap my head around it. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to split your input string by `' '` and get random choices from the resulting list. Something like:

```
print("Random Name Picker")

input_string = str(input("Input names: "))
if input_string == "exit":
    exit()
nameList = input_string.split(' ')
print("Our contestants for this round are:", nameList)

sampled_list = random.choices(nameList, k=5)
print("Our winners are:", sampled_list)
```

Of course the result might have the same name more than once so just make it a `set(sampled_list)`

Comment: Ah! Thank you for pointing that out for me, I just encountered that problem. I've included set(sampled_list) on my last sampled_list and I'm no longer getting repeats of names. Only problem now is that doesn't always return 5 names, i've received from 2 to 5 so far. Anyway idea as to why?

Comment: It's because a name is picked randomly more than once and are reduced during set operation. You could remove a name from list once it has been picked.

Answer (score 0):

- As I understand your question you need a random list of winners from the entered name so there is a small mistake in your program. Here is your program.

```py
    import random

    print("Random Name Picker")

    input_string = input("Input names: ")
    if input_string == "exit":
        exit()
    print("Our contestants for this round are:", input_string.split(","))
    print("Our winners are:", random.choices(input_string.split(","), k=5))
```

- Firstly, You are not splitting an `input_string` when you pass to the `random.choices()`
  so it will return a list of `characters` as @b9s said.
- Also, you are using `str(input("Input names: "))`. If the prompt argument is present, it is written to standard output without a trailing newline. The `input()` then reads a line from input, converts it to a string (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that.
- If you want unique random names then you can use the below code.

```py
    import random

    print("Random Name Picker")

    input_string = input("Input names: ")
    if input_string == "exit":
        exit()
    name_list = input_string.split(",")
    print("Our contestants for this round are:", name_list)
    s = int(input("Enter a Positive Sample Size : "))
    print("Our winners are:", random.sample(name_list,k=s) if s <= len(name_list) else "Sample larger than population or is negative")
```

- Note that if you are not passing `,` separated values then only use `split()`. It by default split `string` using space.

**Reference:** [Choices Function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) and [Input Function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input)

Comment: Oh hey! This works perfectly apart from some names coming up twice (as Vlad Sirbu mentioned above). Do you know any way to fix that?

Comment: Yes, @Jakob. If you want to remove this redundant names then You can use [Sample](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) function for this but if your sample size is larger then population size then it will raise a `ValueError: Sample larger than population or is negative` So you have to check first in if the condition.

Comment: Also, You can check this [StackOverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30784119/python-random-name-generator-without-getting-dupes)