# Selecting element in a list with constraint in Python

Tags: python

I have a list `[1,2,3,3]`, and I want to select a random element from this list multiple times. However, I don't want my random generator to select the same element from the same index more than once.

What I'm currently have:

```
[1,2,3,3] --> [2] with index 1
[1,2,3,3] --> [1] with index 0       
[1,2,3,3] --> [2] with index 1       (this is wrong because chose the same index)
```

What I want is:

```
[1,2,3,3] --> [2] with index 1
[1,2,3,3] --> [1] with index 0       
[1,2,3,3] --> [3] with index 3       
[1,2,3,3] --> [3] with index 4       (this is perfect, no repeats!)
```

What should I do to solve this issue? The function `random.choice(...)` itself doesn't solve this.

UPDATE: I noticed some of you recommended me to use shuffle. It was a really good idea. But, what if I want to keep track of the original index too at later time? I don't think shuffle and pop could do that, right?

Comment: please see this post; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755538/how-do-i-create-a-list-of-unique-random-numbers

Comment: I would use `shuffle` or something, then pop the list until it's empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shuffle` the list once and then `pop()` returns the last element, reducing the list.

```
>>> from random import shuffle
>>> a=[1,2,3,3]
>>> shuffle(a)
>>> a.pop()
3
>>> a.pop()
2
>>> a.pop()
3
>>> a.pop()
1
```

edit: to keep track of the index using `enumerate`

```
from random import shuffle
a=[1,2,3,3]
b=list(enumerate(a))
shuffle(b)
b.pop()

(3, 3)
```

docs: [enumerate](http://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#enumerate) and [random.shuffle](http://docs.python.org/3.5/library/random.html#random.shuff)

Comment: What if I want to keep track of the original index too tho?

Comment: you can use `enumerate`. https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate

Comment: @thanasisp If you add the enumerate solution I will give +1 vote. Also because the `enumerate` zip will be non-destructive.

Answer (score 2):

The following generator produces `(index, element)` pairs in random order while keeping the original list as it is:

```
def gen(lst):
    lst2 = list(enumerate(lst))
    random.shuffle(lst2)
    for x in lst2:
        yield x

l = [1, 2, 3, 3]
for index, elmnt in gen(l):
    # do stuff
    print(index, elmnt)
# 0 1
# 2 3
# 3 3
# 1 2
```

Comment: You are using `enumeration` just what I need! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use random.sample.

`random.sample(population, k)`

Returns a k length list of unique elements chosen from the population sequence or set. Used for random sampling without replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Use @thanasisp's solution and use `shuffle` along with `zip` to keep track of the indices:

```
a = range(10, 15)
b = zip(a, range(len(a))) # pairs of values and indices

import random
random.shuffle(list(b)) # list() evaluates the zip

a_shuffle, idxes = list(zip(*b))
# e.g. [(13, 11, 10, 14, 12), (3, 1, 0, 4, 2)]
```

Comment: @thanasisp suggestion ot use `enumerate` is even better, because that bascially is what this zip does. :-)

Comment: I see, Im going to give it a try. Thanks!