# How to annotate subplots in Plotly inside a for loop

Tags: pandas, plotly, subplot

I am trying to annotate my subplots inside a for loop. Each subplot will have RMS value printed on the plot. I tried to do it the following way:

```
from plotly import tools
figg = tools.make_subplots(rows=4, cols=1)

fake_date = {"X":   np.arange(1, 101, 0.5), "Y": np.sin(x), "Z": [x + 1 for x in range(10)] * 20}
fake_date = pd.DataFrame(fake_date)
fake_date.sort_values("Z")

unique_ids = fake_date['Z'].unique()
train_id, test_id = np.split(np.random.permutation(unique_ids), [int(.6 * len(unique_ids))])


for i, j in enumerate(test_id):

    x_test = fake_date[fake_date['Z'].isin([test_id[i]])] 
    y_test = fake_date[fake_date['Z'].isin([test_id[i]])]


    # Evaluate 
    rms_test = 0.04
    r_test = 0.9



    Real = {'type' : 'scatter',
                     'x' : x_test.X,
                     'y' : x_test.Y,
                "mode" : 'lines+markers', 
                "name" : 'Real'}




    figg.append_trace(Real, i+1, 1)


figg['layout'].update( annotations=[dict(x = 10,y = 0.2,  text= rms_test, xref= "x1",yref="y1")]  )
figg['layout'].update(height=1800, width=600, title='Testing')
pyo.iplot(figg)
```

This does not work, although the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755538/how-do-i-create-a-list-of-numbers-without-duplicates) seems to work for others. Can anyone point out what wrong am I doing? 
I generated fake date for reproducibility

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure where to exactly place the RMS value, but below is a sample code which will help you achieve what you want.

We create an array `annotation_arr` where we store the annotations using the for loop.

We need to set the `xval` and `yval` for each of the individual axes. Remember, first axis will be `x`, second will be `x2` so, I have written a ternary condition for that, please checkout the below code and let me know if there is any issues!

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs,init_notebook_mode,plot,iplot
from plotly import tools
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
rows = 4
figg = tools.make_subplots(rows=rows, cols=1)

fake_date = {"X":   np.arange(0, 100, 0.5), "Y": [np.sin(x) for x in range(200)], "Z": [x + 1 for x in range(10)] * 20}
fake_date = pd.DataFrame(fake_date)
fake_date.sort_values("Z")

unique_ids = fake_date['Z'].unique()
train_id, test_id = np.split(np.random.permutation(unique_ids), [int(.6 * len(unique_ids))])
top = 0
annotation_arr = []
for i, j in enumerate(test_id):

    x_test = fake_date[fake_date['Z'].isin([test_id[i]])] 
    y_test = fake_date[fake_date['Z'].isin([test_id[i]])]


    # Evaluate 
    rms_test = 0.04
    r_test = 0.9



    Real = {'type' : 'scatter',
                     'x' : x_test.X,
                     'y' : x_test.Y,
                "mode" : 'lines+markers', 
                "name" : 'Real'}


    top = top + 1/rows
    i_val = "" if i == 0 else i + 1
    annotation_arr.append(dict(x = r_test,y = top,  text= rms_test, xref= "x"+str(i_val),yref="y"+str(i_val)))
    figg.append_trace(Real, i+1, 1)


figg['layout'].update( annotations=annotation_arr  )
figg['layout'].update(height=1800, width=600, title='Testing')
iplot(figg)
```