# Get all Objects one by one but in a random way

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Here is the code from an other post :

```
from random import randint
count = article.objects.all().count()
random_index = randint(0, count - 1)
all_articles_query =  article.objects.all()
article = all_articles_query[random_index]
```

but now i would like to remove article from the list all_articles_query, and multiple time. I would like to sort a list of article then a random article and each time i sort a random article to move it from the list of article.

I would like to get all article one by one but in a random way.

Regards

Comment: `article.objects.order_by('?')`

Comment: This will kill the database I mean it's heavy costly @heemayl

Comment: have any different if you have `all_articles_query` with random position, and get each in for loop?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9755548/5612363) should solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try like this using [random.randrange](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange):

```
import random

article_list = list(article.objects.all())  # evaluating queryset before everything

while article_list:
    sample = article_list.pop(random.randrange(len(article_list)))
    print(sample)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Custom model manager to do that.

```
class ArticleManager(models.Manager):
    def random(self):
        count = self.aggregate(count=Count('id'))['count']
        random_index = randint(0, count - 1)
        return self.all()[random_index]
```

Then in Article model

```
class Article(models.Model):
    ...
    random_objects = ArticleManager()
```

Then in query use

```
Article.random_objects.random()
```

Comment: this will be get duplicate item, if number count small enough

Comment: How it will return duplicate? Can you elaborate?

Comment: if you run `Article.random_objects.random()` so many times, it can return same object in 2 times `random()`

Comment: No. I test it. all time it returns 1 object. Can you check please?

Comment: print it in `for i in xrange(0,1000):` and you can see what happen