# Error while running an array within function in python

Tags: python, interpolation

RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
While trying to insert array to an function

```
import numpy as np
import random

def lagrange(x, y, x_int):
    n = x.size
    y_int = 0

    for i in range(0, n):
        p = y[i]
        for j in range(0, n):
            if i != j:
               p = p * (x_int - x[j]) / (x[i] - x[j])
        y_int = y_int + p
    return [y_int]

x = []
y = []
for i in range(1000):
   x.append(random.randint(0,100))
   y.append(random.randint(0,100))

fx = 3.5
print(lagrange(np.array(x),np.array(y),fx))
```

i expected to have 1000 iteration of output of an output, any solution to these problems?

Comment: to handle zero division error, use `np.divide()`: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.divide.html

Answer (score 2):

Your error message refers to a function not mentioned in your code. But I assume the issue is because `x[i]` and `x[j]` could be the same number, and therefore you are dividing by zero on your `p = p * (x_int - x[j]) / (x[i] - x[j])` line, which is not possible. You will need to add an exemption to do something different in the case `x[i]` equals `x[j]`.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're generating your `x` array randomly from a range of `(0,100)`, and the array size is 1000, it's guranteed that `x[i] = x[j]` for some `i,j`. You need to ensure elements in `x` are unique.

See: [How do I create a list of random numbers without duplicates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755538/how-do-i-create-a-list-of-random-numbers-without-duplicates)

Answer (score 0):

In your nested loop could it be that you meant to do if x[i] != x[j]:

Those would be the values you wouldn't want to be the same in your division.