# Python number array program

Tags: python

I have to create a program where the user input asks how many numbers in an array and you have to print those numbers from an array.

Example:

How many values to add to the array:

`12`

`[14, 64, 62, 21, 91, 25, 75, 86, 13, 87, 39, 48]`

I don't know how to get all the numbers in one line and how to get different numbers each time. This is what I have so far:

```
import random


x = int(input("How many values to add to the array: "))

b = random.randint(1,99)
c = random.randint(1,99)

for i in range(x):
    twainQuotes = [random.randint(b,c)]

for i in range(x-1):
    print(twainQuotes)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a list of random numbers without duplicates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755538/how-do-i-create-a-list-of-random-numbers-without-duplicates)

Comment: Well, he never specified, so I'm pretty sure you can have duplicates.

Comment: The the phrase "how to get different numbers each time" needs to be clarified.

Comment: Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create a list with x random integers 1,99, this should work:

```
integers = []
for i in range(x):
    integers.append(random.randint(1,99))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this code:

```
import random
x = int(input("How many values to add to the array: "))

b = random.randint(1,99)
c = random.randint(1,99)

twainQuotes = [] # Initialize list
for i in range(x):
    twainQuotes.append(random.randint(b, c)) # Add random number to list

print(twainQuotes) # Print list
```

If you want, you can also use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
import random
x = int(input("How many values to add to the array: "))

b = random.randint(1,99)
c = random.randint(1,99)

twainQuotes = [random.randint(b, c) for i in range(x)] # Initialize list
print(twainQuotes)
```

I would suggest not using the `b` and `c` values, as you could just do `random.randint(1, 99)`:

```
import random
x = int(input("How many values to add to the array: "))

twainQuotes = [random.randint(1, 99) for i in range(x)] # Initialize list
print(twainQuotes)
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
if b > c:
    b, c = c, b

twainQuotes = [random.randint(b, c) for _ in range(x)]
```

to [print](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print):

```
 print(*twainQuotes, sep='\n')
```

if you want to use `for` loops:

```
import random


x = int(input("How many values to add to the array: "))

b = random.randint(1,99)
c = random.randint(1,99)

if b > c:
    b, c = c, b

twainQuotes = []
for i in range(x):
    twainQuotes.append(random.randint(b,c))

for e in twainQuotes:
    print(e)
```

example output (for input = 2):

```
52
65
```

Comment: to explain list comprehension?

Comment: @AyushGarg I added a link from the docs about list comprehension, very good info

Comment: I m not using `for` loop, `*` it is to  give as non-keyword arguments all the list elements to the print function, you can read more in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print)

Comment: You don't have to explain how to print!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, maybe it's a copy-paste error, but you have two variable declarations on the same line which was not written correctly.

```
# either this :
b = random.randint(1,99)
c = random.randint(1,99)

# or this :
b,c = random.randint(1,99), random.randint(1,99)
```

But, I think your code will return an error if b is bigger than c.

```
for i in range(x):
    twainQuotes = [random.randint(b,c)]
    # if b > c ValueError will be raised
```

Instead, I think you can use the list comprehension method? :)

Check the code below :

```
import random

x = int(input("How many values to add to the array: "))

array = [random.randint(1,99) for each_number in range(x)]

print(array)
```