# how to generate list of sequence number in faster way using python

Tags: python, list, performance, tensor, torch

Anyone can improve processing time to generate list of sequence number ? Here is my code and it needs ~ 0.05 second.

```
import torch
import time
import random
index = [torch.tensor(660000)]
st = time.time()
allowed = [x for x in range(index[0])] + [x for x in range(index[0] + 1,2000)]
index = random.sample(allowed, 1000)
print(time.time()-st)
```

Please advise

thank you

Comment: `[x for x in range(index[0])]` -> `list(range(index[0]))`... but why do you need a `list`? Why won't a `range` object suffice?

Comment: Note, `[x for x in whatever]` should always just be `list(whatever)`

Comment: Also, `np.arange` is probably faster, if a `numpy.ndarray` would work

Comment: It would be easier to answer if we know what you're going to do with the list

Comment: There is random.sample afterwards that requires a list. Actually, I would like to use code in github here [link] https://github.com/akwasigroch/Pretext-Invariant-Representations/blob/master/utils.py in return_random function but I feel the performance is slow

Comment: *I feel the performance is slow* -- Why?  If you're going to be doing tensor processing, that is going to vastly overwhelm the processing here.  First, get your app running.  THEN decide if parts are too slow.

Comment: I tested this part take the longest time. In the end of the day the whole process requires ~ 12 hours for one epoch. I think the improvement in this part would bring the faster time.

Answer (score 0):

This should help with OP specific case, not with "generate list of sequence number" stated in question title.

You do not need to create whole list, you can provide the range, this will work with same speed regardless of range size.

```
index = random.sample(range(index[0]), 1000)
```

On my machine it is ~100x faster for range size 1 million

---

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9755548/4601890)

Comment: sorry, I have edited the code. how to implement your suggestion for range something like [x for x in range(index[0])] + [x for x in range(index[0] + 1,2000)] inside random.sample ? so, there is if conditional for the range.

Comment: @AryoWibowo you can sample both ranges the same way I did, then you can randomly choose which range to use (using weighted random) for each sample `is_first_range = random.random() < first_range_weight`  you could also use Numpy functions for all of this (`np.random.choice`, `np.random.random`)