# how to make a random.choice not choose the same twice

Tags: python

I am wondering if their is any way to make a random.choice command not chose the same twice

for example:

```
import random
temp = 0
list_ = ["apple", "orange", "banana"]
while (temp == 0):
    temp2 = random.choice(list_)
    print (temp2)
```

how do i make it not print the same fruit twice

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a list of random numbers without duplicates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755538/how-do-i-create-a-list-of-random-numbers-without-duplicates)

Answer (score 1):

instead of using `ranndom.choice`, maybe use `pop` and `shuffle`:

```
list_ = ["apple", "orange", "banana"]
new_list= list_[:]
random.shuffle (new_list)
for i in range(3):
    print(new_list.pop())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [random.sample](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) with `k=len(list_)` to create a new list that has been shuffled:

```
>>> random.sample(list_, k=len(list_))
['banana', 'apple', 'orange']
```

Comment: The way the user has written this, I assume that the desire is to not alter the original list. It the original list CAN be altered, shuffle is preferred.

Comment: You are right on that -- sometimes fingers are faster than brain cells.