# how to choose a random 5 strings out of 10

Tags: python, random

I have one list consisting of 10 questions. How do I choose 5 (max) at random and there can be no doubles - in python.

I have tried using:

```py
from random import choice

strings = ['aa','bb','cc','dd','ee']
print(choice(strings))
```

But have no Idea how to choose 5 and have no doubles.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a list of random numbers without duplicates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755538/how-do-i-create-a-list-of-random-numbers-without-duplicates)

Answer (score 2):

The method `random.choice()` draws samples *with replacement*.
What you want is drawing samples *without replacment*. This is what `random.sample()` does.

Example with 5 samples drawn:

```
print(random.sample(strings, 5))
```

See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample).

Comment: I believe this is exactly the same as my answer

Comment: I believe we wrote our answers at the same time then.

Comment: I believe mine was first (1 min earlier to be exact). Its ok anyway.

Comment: "The method random.choice() draws samples with replacement." - It also draws samples *without* replacement.

Comment: I certainly took more than a minute to compose my answer. @KellyBundy Maybe you are talking about numpy.random.choice?

Comment: No I'm not. But *you* are probably talking about random.choices().

Comment: I'm talking about calling random.choice() multiple times which, being stateless, always leads to replacement.

Comment: That involves other code, though, not just "the method random.choice". That other code is to "blame" then. If I likewise call random.sample multiple times, that can likewise lead to duplicates.

Comment: I stand by my explanation as an accurate description of the matter from the point-of-view of how these two methods are applied (ie, their intended use). I also believe their wording is carefully chosen to reflect this distinction.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
import random
random.sample(strings, 5)
```

Comment: It would be nicer if you can put in the relevant link and some explanations.

Comment: @DanielHao thanks for the note. However, that has been done by the other answers indeed.