# generate unique id code in faker data set

Tags: python

im trying to create a data set with a unique id code but i get a

> **'ValueError not enough values to unpack (expected 6, got 5)'**

on line 8, basically, I am trying to:

1. generate a unique 6 digit id code
2. append dataset value with 'ID' ex: ID123456

UPDATE:
**fixed the error and ID append, now how  do i make sure the generated id is unique in the dataset?**

```
from faker import Faker
import random
import pandas as pd

Faker.seed(0)
random.seed(0)
fake = Faker("en_US") 
fixed_digits = 6
concatid = 'ID'
idcode,name, city, country, job, age = [[] for k in range(0,6)] 
for row in range(0,100):
    idcode.append(concatid + str(random.randrange(111111, 999999, fixed_digits)))
    name.append(fake.name())
    city.append(fake.city())
    country.append(fake.country())
    job.append(fake.job())
    age.append(random.randint(20,100))

d = {"ID Code":idcode, "Name":name, "Age":age, "City":city, "Country":country, "Job":job}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df.head()
```

planning to generate 1k rows

Comment: Change `range(0,5)` to `range(0,6)`

Comment: 'Generator' object has no attribute 'city_name' inside faker. `city_name.append(fake.city_name())`

Comment: @mx0 fixed the errors thanks and ID append, nowhow do i make sure the generated id are really unique in the data set?

Comment: like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755538/how-do-i-create-a-list-of-random-numbers-without-duplicates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the question:

> now how do I make sure the generated id is unique in the dataset?

You have to use: `unique.random_int`

So, your code will be like this as you see below:

```
from faker import Faker
import random
import pandas as pd

Faker.seed(0)
random.seed(0)
fake = Faker("en_US") 
fixed_digits = 6
concatid = 'ID'
idcode,name, city, country, job, age = [[] for k in range(0,6)] 

for row in range(0,100):
    idcode.append(concatid + str(fake.unique.random_int(min=111111, max=999999)))
    name.append(fake.name())
    city.append(fake.city())
    country.append(fake.country())
    job.append(fake.job())
    age.append(random.randint(20,100))

d = {"ID Code":idcode, "Name":name, "Age":age, "City":city, "Country":country, "Job":job}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df.head()
```