# Python print random lines without repetitions

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I have a little python program which print random HEX string, it generates one HEX string each time I run the program.
i want the program to only generate a HEX string one's, that means the program should not generate a string that has already generated been generated.

**EXAMPLE**

```
python3 program.py

1. ab6b

2. 4c56

3. 1b13

4. ae8d
```

The next example show that the output is random and the program repeats lines.

```
1b13

ae8d

4c56

ae8d
```

**My Code**

```
import os
import binascii

print(binascii.hexlify(os.urandom(2)).decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a list of random numbers without duplicates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755538/how-do-i-create-a-list-of-random-numbers-without-duplicates)

Answer (score 5):

We could store all previously generated strings and check any new string against this list, but you might run out of unique strings after a large number of runs.

```
import os
import binascii

generated_hexes = set()

while True:
    new_hex = binascii.hexlify(os.urandom(2)).decode('utf-8')
    if new_hex not in generated_hexes:
        print(new_hex)
        generated_hexes.add(new_hex)
```

Answer (score 1):

For this situation, you need to store the codes in someplace, like a list in Python.

After this, is necessary to check if the new code exists in this list.

You can adapt the following code as you need.

```
import os
import binascii

list_codes = []

num = 1

while num == 1:
    hex = binascii.hexlify(os.urandom(2)).decode('utf-8')
    if hex not in list_codes:
      list_codes.append(hex)
      print(hex)
    num = int(input("Press 1 to continue "))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the values you print and before printing the next value, check if it's been printed before.

```
import os
import binascii

previously_printed = []
def print_new_random_hex():
    random_hex = binascii.hexlify(os.urandom(2)).decode('utf-8')
    while random_hex in previously_printed:
        random_hex = binascii.hexlify(os.urandom(2)).decode('utf-8')
    print(random_hex)
    previously_printed.append(random_hex)
```

---

In order to have the computer remember what was printed from a previous run, you need to have another file going which saves the values you print. In the code below, the file is `previously_printed.txt`

```
import os
import binascii

with open('previously_printed.txt', 'r') as file:
    previously_printed = file.read().split('\n')

with open('previously_printed.txt', 'a') as file:
    random_hex = binascii.hexlify(os.urandom(2)).decode('utf-8')
    while random_hex in previously_printed:
        print("yay we avoided printing", random_hex, "a second time!")
        random_hex = binascii.hexlify(os.urandom(2)).decode('utf-8')

    print(random_hex)
    file.write('\n' + random_hex)
```

Comment: It doesn't print any output

Comment: Try calling the function. If you're looking to have the code remember what was printed in previous runs, you'll have to save to a file. Is that what you're looking for?