# Choose random elements from huge range without duplicates

Tags: python, random

I have this implementation of the Miller-Rabin-Primetest:

```
def miller_rabin(n, rounds = 40):
    if n == 1:
        return False
    if n in [2, 3]:
        return True
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return False
    d = n - 1
    s = 1
    while d % 2 == 0:
        d = d // 2
        s += 1
    chosen = []
    for _ in range(rounds):
        a = random.randrange(2, n-1)
        x = gmpy2.powmod(a, d, n)
        for _ in range(s):
            y = gmpy2.powmod(x, 2, n)
            if y == 1 and x != 1 and x != n-1:
                return False
            x = y
        if y != 1:
            return False
    return True
```

It does 40 rounds by default.
Every time it chooses a random element from range(2, n-1).
Now I wanted to know whether there is a fast possibility to exclude duplicates.
if I do

```
values = random.sample(range(2, n-1), rounds)
```

I get the Error:  Python int too large to convert to C ssize_t

Comment: How does `random.sample()` relate to  `miller_rabin()` ??

Comment: @Luuk: The miller-rabin primality test requires selecting a number of random *bases* according to certain criteria and applying a subsidiary test to them. If, by chance, a random choice repeats an earlier selection then no further information is gained and the effort to test it is wasted.

Comment: so this question is a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9755548/724039 ??

Comment: @Luuk: I think not, because that question is implicitly about small ranges and this one is implicitly about large ranges that are too large to work with `random.sample`. It would be better if this question explicitly mentioned the size of the values of `n` being considered.

Comment: There are random permutation generators that are fast and use very little memory, though they're not available in the `random` module. However, this is an unnecessary complication for miller-rabin (MR). For small numbers, say 64-bit or less, you should use the deterministic variant of MR. For larger numbers, bear in mind that MR is ultimately a probabilistic test. Thus, the probability of a repeat in the selection of a base `a` may also be taken into account and overcome by using more rounds. For cryptographic-sized primes (>=256 bits), the probability is so small it may be ignored.

Comment: I concur that if you're experiencing this error then `n` is so large that collisions are so improbable as to be zero for all intents and purposes. It will take a universe lifetime to encounter a collision (that's why UUIDs are so-called universally-unique). So, what are your closest realistic values of `n` and `rounds`? (One universe lifetime in seconds is only 40 bits long)

Comment: What's the point of `chosen`? You're not using it.

Answer (score 1):

A big factor in how to handle the problem is how large `n` is. If it is less than `2**63`, you can simply use

```
random.sample(range(n), rounds)
```

to get a list of unique values having the desired size.

For larger values of `n`, the probability of collisions is very close to zero with small sample sizes such as 40. If you want to be absolutely sure though, the simplest solution is to use a rejection technique. This is very easy to implement with a Python `set()`, which guarantees the uniqueness of its elements. The following code illustrates this:

```
import random

def unique_rand_set(n, lower_bd = 2, qty = 40):
    if n < 2**63:
        return random.sample(range(lower_bd, n-1), qty)
    s = set()
    while len(s) < qty:
        s.add(random.randrange(lower_bd, n))
    return s

# The following code just demonstrates usage of the function
n = 1 << 100
my_set = unique_rand_set(n, 5)
for value in my_set:
    print(value)
```

Given the `unique_rand_set()` function above, you would change

```
for _ in range(rounds):
    a = random.randrange(2, n-1)
    ...
```

to

```
my_set = unique_rand_set(n)
for a in my_set:
    ...
```

Note that since both lists and sets are iterable, `for a in my_set:` works regardless of which type the function returns.

We know from the [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) that you don't start getting significant probability of collisions until you start getting up to O(sqrt(rounds)) values being generated, so you could generate millions of values and be very unlikely to get any rejection cases.

Answer (score 0):

The *full* traceback of that error points to the random module trying to get the `len` of the input range.

Apparently somewhere in the path to get the `len` of the range object, it tries to cast the Python bigint to a 64 bit C integer and then back to a Python bigint. <sub>Don’t ask me why it does this silly casting — it could just use Python bigints the whole way ands avoid this problem.</sub>

One of the comments suggested using `random.shuffle()` but it uses `len` too so it likely might suffer from the same problem.

Not sure how to avoid this without completely reimplementing `random.sample()`.